# What I'm doing wrong with this preg_replace code to embed videos?

Tags: php, iframe, preg-replace, embed

I'm trying to embed videos directly from the link

Link Example

```
https://www.example.com/video22818393/dancing_with_the_moon
```

The Standard Embed code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/embedframe/22818393" frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no allowfullscreen=allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

My Code to embed the video directly from link:

```
$post[message] = preg_replace('/<a href="https?:\/\/www\.example\.com\/video([a-z0-9A-Z]+)\/([a-z0-9A-Z]+)" target="_blank">(.+?)<\/a>/', '<iframe src="https://www.example.com/embedframe/$1" frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no allowfullscreen=allowfullscreen></iframe>', $post[message]);
```

But with this code just show the site link instead the video, so anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Replace last `([a-z0-9A-Z]+)` with `([^\/]+)`, use `'~<a\s+href="https?://www\.example\.com/video([a-z0-9A-Z]+)/([^/]+)" target="_blank">(.*?)</a>~'`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @WiktorStribiżew , I tried but it does not work either

Comment: is it just the number of the video you need?

Comment: It actually works, see https://3v4l.org/doBLj